# Instantiating a set amount of unique objects from a single method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, factory-pattern

This is something I've just never been able to get my brain around...

Let's say I am building a grid of 8 UIViews wide by 8 UIViews high. It could by any x, y set.  It doesn't have to be 8 x 8.  Let's just be arbitrary and stick to that for now.

This init method (part of a subclass of UIView) generates a row 8 UIViews wide:

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;

    //row 01
    UIView* row01Square01 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((0*x), (0*y), x, y)];
    [self addSubview:row01Square01];

    UIView* row01Square02 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((1*x), (0*y), x, y)];
    [self addSubview:row01Square02];

    UIView* row01Square03 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((2*x), (0*y), x, y)];
    [self addSubview:row01Square03];

    UIView* row01Square04 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((3*x), (0*y), x, y)];
    [self addSubview:row01Square04];

    UIView* row01Square05 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((4*x), (0*y), x, y)];
    [self addSubview:row01Square05];

    UIView* row01Square06 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((5*x), (0*y), x, y)];
    [self addSubview:row01Square06];

    UIView* row01Square07 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((6*x), (0*y), x, y)];
    [self addSubview:row01Square07];

    UIView* row01Square08 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((7*x), (0*y), x, y)];
    [self addSubview:row01Square08];
}

return self;
```

}

Is it possible to write a method that could use that code (with modifications of course) to generate the subsequent 7 rows of UIViews?  Better yet, is it possible to use 1 line of to generate all 64 UI Views?

I have experimented with using a for, while, do loop, but I admit I am completely lost when it comes to whether you or not you can pass a string as an argument to an init method.

Thanks in advance for any insight into this.

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll also need to release the UIViews after adding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
    UIView* square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i*x), (0*y), x, y)];
    [self addSubview:square];
    }
```

Or (for all the rows):

```
for(int r=0;r<8;r++) {
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
        UIView* square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i*x), (r*y), x, y)];
        [self addSubview:square];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, that part makes sense.  The part that confuses me is how can I access one of the individual UIViews generated by this code elsewhere.  My gut tells me that I would add a setTag line to the loop then use viewWithTag to access a particular instance.

Comment: Well you know the order they were created in so they will be in that order in self.subViews and you could retrieve a specific one with objectAtIndex, or yes you could loop through instead.

Comment: Trying to get a specific view by accessing self.subviews by index is fragile.  You're better off either adding a tag to each view and accessing them by tag, or storing references to your subviews in an array member variable.  Using tags is probably the best approach if you don't need to access the views after they have been removed form their superview.

Answer (score 1):

```
int numberOfRows = 8;
int numberOfColumns = 8;

for (int j = 0; j<numberOfRows;j++){
    for (int i=0;i<numberOfColumns;i++) {
        UIView* square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i*x), (j*y), x, y)];
        [self addSubview:square];
    }
}
```